# Check if image is binary

Tags: imagemagick

I tried to convert an image `jpg` file to binary image, I mean, only B&W colors.

I run `convert -monochromatic in.jpg out.jpg` and the result is visually satisfactory.

Then I tried to check if the image really contains only B&W colors. So I run `identify -verbose out.jpg` and the result was too long.

But the main part I'd like to show here is the following:

```
  Type: Grayscale
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 3978000
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 188.613 (0.739659)
      standard deviation: 111.739 (0.438194)
      kurtosis: -0.804836
      skewness: -1.0932
  Colors: 12
  Histogram:
    883301: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
    109638: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
     35348: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
      6126: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
       570: (  4,  4,  4) #040404 gray(4)
        30: (  5,  5,  5) #050505 gray(5)
        36: (250,250,250) #FAFAFA gray(250)
       980: (251,251,251) #FBFBFB gray(251)
     10689: (252,252,252) #FCFCFC gray(252)
     64396: (253,253,253) #FDFDFD gray(253)
    195093: (254,254,254) #FEFEFE gray(254)
   2671793: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)
```

So what is strange to me is the **Colors: 12** line. Does it mean that the image is not B&W? Should it be only 2?

**Edit:** based on answer below, the command should be `convert -threshold` and the important part from `identify` info is *Channel*.

But even with this last option, I get 8-bit not 1-bit.

```
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 8-bit
```

Comment: The JPEG standard does not allow use of 1-bit per pixel, it always uses 8-bits, or potentially more if JPEG2000. PNG format (and BMP and others) allow 1-bit per pixel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for letting me know about this fact on `jpg` format. But in this case, can I still say that my image file is a binary one?

Comment: Not really - JPEG blurs edges and smears things out to save space.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, so should I convert to `png` first? Could I loose information doing this?

Comment: You won't lose any information as PNG is lossless. Use `convert input.jpg -monochromatic result.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I think that the option is  `-monochrome`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

[Monochromatic colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_color) are all the colors (tints, tones, and shades) of a single hue. So monochromatic does not mean binary image.

You convert a colored image to a binary image using thresholding and obviously you need to give a threshold value to determine what values will be 1(white), what values will be 0(black). By calling values I mean the value term in [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)(hue-saturation-value). We can call it lightness also.

So you can achieve this task by:

```
convert colored.png -threshold 75% thres_colored.png
```

**computer-158675_1280.png**

[image]

Command:

```
identify -verbose computer-158675_1280.png
```

Result:

```
Image: computer-158675_1280.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1280x1046+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```

Convert it to a binary image:

```
convert computer-158675_1280.png -threshold 75% binary.png
```

**binary.png**

[image]

Command:

```
identify -verbose binary.png
```

Result:

```
Image: binary.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1280x1046+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
```

Eventually, the criteria for checking a binary image is not `Colors:` part but the `Channel depth:` part. `gray: 1-bit` means binary image in here.

Comment: Thanks. I read about this option, but I don't know the better value to use. I tried 50%; you suggested 75%. I'll try.

Comment: @Sigur It depends on the image. I will make some additions and answer "Check if an image is binary or not".

Comment: With 75% I see that the image contains more black parts, I mean, it is more dense. But the -verbose still shows 12 values on Histogram. Should I worry with that or it is not possible to obtains only 2?

Comment: @Sigur I have completed my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now, partially. I tried with 75% and I got `Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth: gray: 8-bit`. Should it be `1bit`? My image is `jpg`.

Comment: @Sigur Please share the image you are dealing with in your question if it's possible. Also please share the exact command that you are using in your question. Lastly, please mark my answer as the correct answer if it's fair.

Comment: OK, thanks. The image is not mine, so I have to ask permission, only tomorrow. I'll edit the Q. Thanks for a while.

Comment: @Sigur Could you mark my answer as the correct answer? Because I think it deserves.

Comment: Thanks. But usually I wait for more possible answers. I can accept only one.

Comment: @Sigur Oh, OK then.